# How can I allow users to edit CSS in a WYSIWYG editor

Tags: wysiwyg

Is there a way to give the administrator of a site the ability to edit and save CSS files in a wysiwyg editor? I thought perhaps the CSS could be node therefor allowing for some type of versioning and reversion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be interested in this module:

[CSS Injector](http://drupal.org/project/css_injector)

> Allows administrators to inject CSS into the page output based on
>   configurable rules. It's useful for adding simple CSS tweaks without
>   modifying a site's official theme